# Create .MSG or .OFT Outlook Files From HTML (via JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, outlook, msg, oft

**The Need:**

Essentially I have a tool that creates HTML Emails. A feature I would like to add for this tool is to create `.MSG` or `.OFT` files for use specifically in Outlook so the client doesn't have to load the HTML into outlook and create their own `.MSG` or `.OFT` files manually. This has to be done in either PHP or JS via my tool, NOT done manually in Outlook.

**The Problem**

It appears these files are Binary Files and I cannot find a JS Library that handles the conversion. If the client uploads the HTML directly into Outlook, then Outlook modifies the HTML in such a way that it often breaks the email. If I had more control over the conversation I could hopefully fix a few of the rendering issues.

**What I've Tried**

I exported `.EML` Files successfully, but once imported into Outlook and converted, these too break in the same manner as straight HTML.

---

Any thoughts greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you've tried EML, what makes you think MSG woudl be any better? What exactly breaks for EML?

Comment: The most obvious issue is `direction:ltr` doesn't get added if inside a parent node with `direction:rtl`. This is done for multi-column mobile rendering. I was hoping since the `.msg` file already processes the HTML that I could do some sort of post-compiled checking and fix errors that Outlook would then just insert . But with `.eml` the processing is done by the client in outlook.

Comment: MSG file won't be any different from EML. You'd need to fix your HTML - keep in mind that HTML in Outlook is rendered by Word, not IE.